# The answers to these questions are?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

> 1. C is the correct answer to how many questions?

A.  1
B.  2
C.  3
D.  4

> 2. Which letter is the correct answer fewer times than any other?

A.  D
B.  B
C.  C
D.  A

> 3. Which letter is the correct answer more times than any other?

A.  D
B.  C
C.  B
D.  A

> 4. Which one of these is the only true statement?

A.  There are four questions with the answer A.
B.  A is the right answer to exactly one question.
C.  B is never the right answer.
D.  There is an equal amount of A's and C's among the correct answers

> 5.When is A the correct answer for the first time?

A.  On the fifth question
B.  On the sixth question
C.  On the seventh question
D.  On the first question

> 6.How many occurrences of the most common answer are there?

A.  3
B.  4
C.  5
D.  6

> 7.Which ones are the only two consecutive questions with the same answer?

A.  2 and 3
B.  7 and 8
C.  1 and 2
D.  4 and 5

> 8.Which question is the only one with the same answer as this one?

A. 4
B. 2
C. 3
D. 7

Original source: [Self-Referential Quiz](https://mollikka.github.io/Self-referentialQuiz/the-incredible-eight.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answers:

> 1:B, 2:D, 3:C, 4:B, 5:B, 6:A, 7:D, 8:C

Starting Point:

> 8 cannot be D, as 7 also being D would contradict the 7/8 relationship. It cannot be A, because question 4 would imply 4 A's, and 8 forces only 2. It cannot be B because 2 answers is a full quarter of the 8 available, so cannot be the single lowest number of occurrences. Therefor 8 is C, and 3 is also C.

This allows us to:

> State that answer 1 is B, and that none of the remaining answers can be C. Then, since 2 cannot be B or C as stated earlier, and can't be A because of question 5, 2 must be D. 4 can't be A or D because of 2, or C as previously established, therefor 4 must be B.

Now we are at:

> 1:B, 2:D, 3:C, 4:B, 5:?, 6:? 7:?, 8:C; and so 7 must be D, which forces 5 to be B and 6 to be A.

Comment: Aha, you got there first :-)

Answer (score 5):

### Deduction

Question 8 tells us that one of the four letters is the answer to exactly two questions.

Consider the answer to **question 8**:

- If it's D, then the answer to question 7 is D not B, contradiction.
- If it's A, then the answer to question 4 is A, so there are at least 4 A's, contradiction.
- If it's B, then the answer to question 2 is B, so B is the rarest answer with at least two occurrences, contradiction.

> So we have **8C** and therefore **3C**. Thus, among the answers, C appears exactly twice and B appears the most times. This also gives us **1B**.

Consider the answer to **question 7**:

- It can't be B or C, by the last spoilertag above.
- If it's A, then the answer to question 2 is also C, contradiction.

> So we have **7D**. By question 5, we know there is at least one answer A, so each letter appears at least once among the answers.

Consider the answer to **question 6**:

- If it's D, then the distribution of answers is 0/0/2/6 in some order, and question 2 has no unique answer, contradiction.
- It can't be C, by the second-to-last spoilertag above.
- If it's B, then the distribution of answers is 1/1/2/4 or 0/2/2/4. In the first case, question 2 has no unique answer; in the second case, one of the letters never appears among the answers. Contradiction.

> So we have **6A**. Thus the answers are three B's, two C's, and either two A's and one D or two D's and one A. The only answers we don't know are 2, 4, and 5, two of which must be B. Clearly the answer to question 2 isn't B, so we have **4B** and **5B**. This tells us the final answer, **2D**.

### Final answer

> 1B, 2D, 3C, 4B, 5B, 6A, 7D, 8C.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the detailed deduction helped me understand further more! thank you!